# m3u8 split into audio and video frames stream simultaneously

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-streaming, audio-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to capture live m3u8 stream in python and split it into two streams: rawaudio and rawvideo. Then to analyze them separately.

It is possible to get both streams separately  by using ffmpeg

for audio

```
import subprocess
videolink = 'http://20.7.7.1:8080/live/xyz.m3u8'
command = ['ffmpeg','-v','0', '-i', videolink, '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-ac', '2', '-ar', '48000', '-f', 's16le', '-']
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
while True:
    raw_audio = proc.stdout.read(192000) #reads 1s audio
```

for video

```
import subprocess
videolink = 'http://20.7.7.1:8080/live/xyz.m3u8'
command = ['ffmpeg','-v','0', '-i', videolink,'-f', 'image2pipe',
       '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24','-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-']
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
while True:
    raw_video = proc.stdout.read(432*240*3) #reads 1 frame
```

In this case if I compare obtained results from these streams I can get time differences.
My question is: Is it possible to capture both streams simultaneously using one command?

Comment: It is, then the audio + video data needs, at the least, to be interleaved so some container is needed to be specified in ffmpeg and the output needs to be demuxed within python.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I couldn't find such container. I wrote if somebody knows